# Which Parse api to use?

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, web-hosting

I am tasked to build a web application for data entry. Users will be able to log in and enter some data via browser. The data will be stored in Parse data tables. The web app should be easy and quick to build.

Is Parse able to host my HTMLs? I can program with JavaScript, but wonder which API I should use, JavaScript, REST or Cloud api? Any limitation as to my requirements? Which is the quickest way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes parse can hold your HTML and you can host your site on it, you can read more about it [here.](https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide/)

If you are building a web app I would use the JavaScript sdk.

Parse has a lot of documentation and its actually really good. This [here](https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide) would be a good place to start.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jack for your suggestion.

Comment: @alextc If I answered your question please accept it ;)